# CloudWatch Dashboard with Log Insight Query using Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless, dashboard, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have manually created from aws console a CloudWatch Dashboard which contains few widgets from Log Insights Queries. I want to create the same using code (mainly using serverless package). I have found only this [serverless plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-cloudwatch-dashboard) related to cloudwatch dashboard, but it does not create dashboard using log insight query.
This [AWS CloudWatch Code Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/example_cloudwatch_PutMetricData_section.html) also does not show how we can do the same.

I'm using **Typescript** for the project

**Query Exmaple:**

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /REQUEST_ID_GOES_HERE/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take it as an example to create a dashboard with a widget based on a Log Insights query using the Python Boto3

```
import boto3
# Create a CloudWatch client
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

# Define the dashboard body
dashboard_body = {
  "widgets": [
    {
      "type": "logQuery",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "width": 12,
      "height": 6,
      "properties": {
        "query": "fields @timestamp, @message | filter @message like /REQUEST_ID_GOES_HERE/"
      }
    }
  ]
}
# Create the dashboard
cloudwatch.put_dashboard(
  DashboardName='Dashboard',
  DashboardBody=json.dumps(dashboard_body)
)
```

Comment: we cant do directly from the yml file ? and what about the widget title ?